# Windows android sdk packages in Linux

Tags: android

Can i use the `android sdk packages` (both the images for emulator and the sdk patform for ICS) in a Ubuntu android sdk directory.

This is in effect to the large download size of the packages which i dont want to download again. Will simply `copying` those packages and images to the linux android-sdk-linux directory do the work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible to use android sdk for windows in Ubuntu .You have to download android sdk for linux . For installation procedure refer Nickola's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/154905/39372)

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can.The Android SDK can be installed in Ubuntu/Linux with no problem.

Here is the installation process/tutorial:

1)**Installing Eclipse And Prerequisites**

Open Terminal and type `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk eclipse ruby rubygems ruby-dev git ant libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev`

This command will install the eclipse IDE,in which you will develop your android apps,openjdk,ruby and xml.

Notice that the Eclipse version from the software center is older than the latest Android SDK Version and they will be unable to integrate together.You should head to [eclipse.org](http://eclipse.org) and Download the latest linux version from there.Here is the [Link to the direct download link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.2-201202080800/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-linux-gtk.tar.gz).

2)**Installing the Android SDK**

Install the Android SDK by heading to the [Android SDK Page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). Choose the linux version for i386 architecture.

After downloading the file,you have to un-compress it with the following command:

```
cd ~
wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r18-linux_86.tgz
tar xvfz android-sdk_r18-linux_86.tgz
```

This will give you the directory android-sdk-linux_86 in your home directory.

We must add the $HOME/android-sdk-linux_86/tools directory and the $HOME/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools directory to our PATH variable which we do as follows:

Open the Profile file using gedit with the following command:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

Add the following to the end of the file:

```
PATH="$HOME/android-sdk-linux_86/tools:$HOME/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

To make this change effective,run :

```
export PATH="$HOME/android-sdk-linux_86/tools:$HOME/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

Now start the android SDK by typing:

```
android
```

3)**Installing the required packages**

Select `Available packages` in the left panel and then select `Android Repository` in the right panel to download SDK packages:

The packages that belong to the `Android Repository` group should now all be checked. Click on the `Install Selected` button:

At the new window that will popup,click `Accept` and then `Install`. When the installation finishes,close the window.

4)**Integrating The Android SDK Into Eclipse**

Open Eclipse which is located at the programming tools.

Click on `OK` if you see the Workspace Launcher window.

Head to `Help->Install new software...`

The `Available Software` window opens. Click on the `Add...` button:

A small `Add Site` window opens. Fill in the following values and click on OK:

```
Name: `ADT Plugin`

Location: `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
```

In the next window, click `Next` ,accept the license agreements and then click `Finish.`

Your packages are now installed.It is recommended to restart eclipse after the installation.

There is also a final step.Head to `Help->Preferences`

In the `Preferences`  window, select `Android` in the left panel, and then click on the `Browse...` button that belongs to the SDK Location field in the right panel:

Select the directory where the Android SDK is located and click on `OK`.

Back in the Preferences window, click on Apply (you should then see the supported Android versions in the Target Name column) and then click `OK`.

**Setting Up the Emulator**

Type in terminal `android list targets`.

This command will reveal all the android versions that are available.

Go to eclipse and go to `Window->AVD Manager`.Add and remove Android Emulators from that window that will popup.When your app is built and you click `Run->Run` the emulator will open containing your fresh application.

Comment: Exceptional answer. One quick question, when I download the packages the APIs only go up to 17. 18 and 19 are missing, where can I get them?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools "Troubleshooting Ubuntu" explains how to setup Java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can copy android-sdk packages from windows to linux. 
Except the SDK tools and platform tools you can use them all

1. Download the **android-sdk_rxx.x-linux.tgz** and extract to a location which can be accessed by all users.
2. Copy **all the folders in the android-sdk**(from windows machine) except the folders that contain ***.exe** files and paste **inside the extracted android-sdk-linux** in step 1.
3. Then **start eclipse and install the ADT Plugin**, then select Help > Install New Software.(refer [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)).
4. Configure the ADT Plugin:
   Once Eclipse restarts, you must specify the location of your Android SDK directory:
    In the "Welcome to Android Development" window that appears, select Use existing SDKs.
   Browse and select the location of the Android SDK directory you recently downloaded and unpacked(location in step1).
   Click Next.

Your Eclipse IDE is now set up to develop Android apps, but you need to add the latest SDK platform tools and an Android platform to your environment. To get these packages for your SDK, continue to Adding Platforms and Packages.